# Ejecutar función al pulsar tecla con input datepicker

Tags: datepicker, onkeyup

Tengo un campo input text al que le paso la función onKeyUp para que al detectar la tecla intro active el evento click de un boton, no consigo que entre en la función.
Decir que el campo es de tipo datepicker, cuando entras en el, muestra un calendario, no se si tendrá que ver.

Este es el input con class datepicker

```
<input onkeyup="onKeyUp(event,'#btnBuscaAlbaranes') return false;" type="text" id="idFechaInicioA"   class="form-control datepicker  input-sm"  >
```

Funcion a la que le paso el nombre de boton para hacer el click pero no llega ni a entrar.

```
function onKeyUp(event,btn) {
        alert();
        var keyCode = event.keyCode;
        if (keyCode == '13') {
            $(btn).click();
        }
    }
```

Opciones de datepicker

```
function datepicker() {
    $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
        format: "d-m-Y",
        language: 'es',
        timepicker: false,
    });
    $.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');
}
```

Comment: Si tienes un datepicker en el mismo input deberías gestionar lo que quieres hacer asociado a eventos del datepicker, por ejemplo onSelect

Comment: Gracias Carmen pero aun me falta algo de info, el data input type text, aunque le añado la clase datetimepicker tendría que poder detectar la pulsación de teclas no?

Comment: No necesariamente porque al lanzar el calendario ya no estás interaccionando con el campo mediante el teclado. Mira este enlace [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210987/jquery-keyup-input-does-not-detect-change-from-datepicker]

Comment: Gracias carmen y perdona mi torpeza, como podría implementar el ejemplo que me has enseñado? He intentado algo asi     <input   .on("keyup change", "onKeyUp(event,'#btnBuscaAlbaranes'))  return false;" type="text" id="idFechaInicioA"   class="form-control datepicker  input-sm"  > pero entiendo que aun estoy algo lejos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para intentar ejecutar en el evento onSelect del datepicker, cuándo se ha seleccionado una fecha:

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
   format: "d-m-Y",
   language: 'es',
   timepicker: false,
   onSelect: function () {
      $('#btnBuscaAlbaranes').click();
   }
});
```

Otra opción mas cercana a tu planteamiento sería en el onSelect preguntar si hay cambio en el evento keyup, pero esto no lo he probado, se basaría en el enlace que te pasé en el comentario.

```
onSelect: function () {
      $('.datepicker').on("keyup change", function(){
        //Aquí lo que quieres hacer
      });
   }
```

Espero que te sirva